# How do I specify a different color scale for sex in each line plot (i.e., different color scale for y =n and for y = avg_weight)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to use a different color scale for the variable sex to differentiate those lines that correspond to the response variable n and those that correspond to the response variable avg_weight.

```
yearly_sex_weight = surveys_complete %>%
  group_by(year, sex, species_id) %>%
  summarise(
    avg_weight = mean(weight)
  )

yearly_sex_species_counts = surveys_complete %>%
  count(year, sex, species_id)

yearly_sex_weight_count = full_join(yearly_sex_weight, yearly_sex_species_counts)

myplot = ggplot(
  data = yearly_sex_weight_count,
  mapping = aes(x = year)
) 

myplot + 
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_weight, group = sex, color = sex)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = n, color = sex)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(M = "blue", F = "pink")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(species_id)) +
  theme_bw()
```

The data can be found here:

https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/surveys_complete/14589009

This is what I have so far...
[image: Current Progress]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ideas for how you might visualize this data. Note in both examples I start by pivoting the two response variables to a long format (`tidyr::pivot_longer()`).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

To get 4 different colors for the lines, you could map the `interaction` between `sex` and `response`.

```r
yearly_sex_weight_count %>%
  pivot_longer(c(avg_weight, n), names_to = 'response') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color = interaction(sex, response))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(species_id)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(color = 'Sex')
```

[image]

Alternatively, you might stick with the two colors you've used for `sex` and map the different `response` variables to a different aesthetic. I chose `linetype` in this example.

```r
yearly_sex_weight_count %>%
  pivot_longer(c(avg_weight, n), names_to = 'response') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color = sex)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = response)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(species_id)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(M = "blue", F = "pink")
    ) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(color = 'Sex')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>